# Oracle 11g schema selection

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g

I have analyzing an code of application implemented Java SE (Spring) and Oracle 11g. In XXXDaoImpl class there are many queries writte as

```
select * from PREFIX.TableName
```

I have created a schema in oracle 11g via Oracle SQL Developer and imported all tables successfully.
But when an application tries to call any procedure it call MYPREFIX extention lets say

```
   select * from MYPREFIX.TableName
```

I would like to know how to change the MYPREFIX name in  SQL Developer to get code and newly created schema similat each other in order to run the application properly.

I am currently having following error.

```
ERROR 30 May 2013 18:06:02,036 [ChangeDeleteMHandler] [ChangeDeleteMHandler]: Error during change/delete msisdn procedure call
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call TABLENAME.changeM()}]; SQL state [72000]; error code [4063]; ORA-04063: package body "PREFIX.TABLENAME" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "PREFIX.TABLENAME"
ORA-06512: at line 1
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04063: package body "PREFIX.TABLENAME" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "PREFIX.TABLENAME"
ORA-06512: at line 1

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:969)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:125)
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are `PREFIX` and `MYPREFIX` as Oracle Schema users, so in your scenario your application is accessing tables under the `PREFIX` schema and you've created a new `MYPREFIX` schema. If that's the case, you could grant privileges to your schema by running under the `PREFIX`:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON YOUR_TABLE
TO MYPREFIX;
```